# Why is my selected role displaying one letter per selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am attempting to change the registration form for when a user is logged in or out and want to register. This is what I tried:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(_context.Roles.First(x=> x.Name == "Registered Users").Name);
}
else 
{
    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(_context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
}
```

It does display only the one option but it displays it like this. But why?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the constructor for `SelectList` is expecting a collection, and a `string` is basically a collection of `char`s. Try wrapping the `_context.Roles...` stuff in a string array initializer (e.g. `new string[] { ... }`) and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor of SelectList that you use is

```
SelectList(IEnumerable)
```

that initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list.

You pass string as a parameter, so it will recognize as a collection of chars and will display a one letter per selection

you can try to use:

```
    var name = _context.Roles.First(x=> x.Name == "Registered Users").Name;
    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(
       new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem {Text = name , Value = name }
       }
    );
```

Comment: `new List<SelectListIteam>` is superfluous and thus - noise. `new[]` is much more concise and thus more readable (the type of the element can be clearly seen).

Comment: @BartoszKP Thanks, it just  one more example how to implement it. Because you have already described the case with `new[]` :)

Answer (score 1):

To have a single-element list you want to have:

```
new SelectList(new[] { _context.Roles.First(x=> x.Name == "Registered Users").Name });
```

because the `SelectList` constructor expects an `IEnumerable`, i.e. a collection of elements to display. Since string is a collection of characters, it works, but treats your string as a collection of elements to display (i.e. individual characters).

Also note, that your LINQ query doesn't really make sense. If the element that matches the condition exist, the result will always be `"Registered Users"`. Otherwise an exception will be thrown. So, you could simplify this a bit:

```
//a class field perhaps?
private readonly string RegisteredUsersString = "Registered Users";
//...

if (_context.Roles.Any(x => x.Name == RegisteredUsersString))
    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(new[] { RegisteredUsersString });
else
    // throw? display an error?
```